# How to delete all files not in a set

Tags: bash

I have a plain text file with a list of file names. For example,

```
A.doc
E.doc
F.pdf
```

I would like to delete all files in the current directory except for those.

Can this be done in bash?

Comment: Sure - why not ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @PaulR  Is the answer to use `shopt -s extglob` ?  I can see `shopt -s extglob` <newline> `rm !(A.doc|E.doc|F.pdf)`  but that isn't very useful.

Comment: Those files or extensions??

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S Just those files.. Maybe I don't need shopt -s extglob as there is no glob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the list of files *not* to delete is goodfiles.txt.  Then:

```
ls | grep -vx -f goodfiles.txt
```

Gives you the list of "other" files, that you want to delete.  If you confirm those are the files you want to delete, then:

```
ls | grep -vx -f goodfiles.txt | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

Comment: Will this attempt to delete directories? I would only like to delete files.

Comment: @user2179021: It will attempt to delete directories, but those attempts will fail because `rm` without `-r` won't remove directories.  So you're good to go.  If you are picky about the spurious error messages for directories which `rm` won't delete, you could add more code to handle that.

Comment: It's not so much that I am picky, more nervous about doing "rm directorywithallmypreciousdatainit" and relying on it to fail.

Comment: @user2179021: Regarding parsing `ls`, note that I was careful to use `xargs -d '\n'` so the script should work even for filenames with spaces in them (a common Bash gotcha).  My script will *not* work properly for filenames with *newlines* in them, but no sane system should have such files.  If you care a lot about this kind of thing, you can use `find` instead, e.g. `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0` will avoid directories and also print in a special way which supports newlines in filenames.  But it's a lot of trouble for most applications.

Comment: @user2179021: If you're concerned about accidentally removing files that you shouldn't, then use a "files to delete" list instead of a "files not to delete" list.